# Ubuntu Apache taking long time to respond and getting This site can’t be reached

Tags: django, apache, dns

Hi Guys I am trying to route my domain to server 139.5X.X.XXX

Following is My DNS record Details in Hostinger :-

```
Type Name  Priority    Content IP-V4          TTL

A    www    0       139.5X.X.XXX             600    
A    @      0       139.5X.X.XXX             14400
```

Now I am seeing default apache page while browsing the domain (Server serving default apache page (Digital Ocean Ubuntu Droplet)) .

But after configuring a Django service to domain it taking too long to respond and ending up with "This Site can't be Reached"

following is the conf file which I am using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName tellie.in
        ServerAlias www.tellie.in
        Redirect permanent / https://tellie.in/

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =tellie.in [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.tellie.in
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@tellie.in
        ServerName tellie.in
        ServerAlias www.tellie.in
        
        DocumentRoot /home/srv/telli
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/srv/telli/telli/static
        <Directory /home/srv/telli/telli/static>
        Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/srv/telli/telli/media
        <Directory /home/srv/telli/telli/media>

        Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride None
                Require all granted

        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/srv/telli/telli/telli>
            <Files wsgi.py>
               
        Require all granted

            </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess    telli python-path=/home/srv/telli/telli python-home=/home/srv/telli/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup telli
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/srv/telli/telli/telli/wsgi.py
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/tellie.in/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/tellie.in/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there anything wrong that could cause the problem I am facing

Comment: Try adding the site-packages to the python-path's search directories separated by a ':' e.g. `python-path=/home/srv/telli/telli:home/srv/telli/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#adding-additional-module-directories

Also adding the apache error logs might help

Comment: Also check out `mod_wsg-express` command https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/  I found I needed to use the `mod_wsg-express install-module` command so I can set up my wsgi.so set up correctly in the Apache modules

Comment: site is working on 80 port (http).  Not working in 443 (Https ). Seems Like Firewall is blocking 443. I have done ufw disable now it working fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Apache has rx access to the directories under /home/srv/, It is better to move the code out of HOME and in a general mountpoint as /var or /data

Comment: Do you have any source to back it up your claim to move folders?